# Debugging with ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging

I'm working on an existing ASP.NET MVC 3 project on Visual Studio 2010. I'm not very familiar with the technology. I've done a lot of work with ASP.NET Web Forms though. I'm trying to debug something and for some reason, my breakpoints aren't being hit. I know that the code that I'm attempting to debug is being ran. But I don't know why I can't debug.

When I attempt to start debugging, I've noticed that the little round red circles that represent breakpoints stay solid. If I remember correctly, they should change to an empty circle with a red outline to show that the breakpoints are yet to be reached.

What am I missing?

Comment: the solid red dots mean the library is loaded and the breakpoints should be hit.  The red circles mean the code is unreachable (either because the assembly isn't loaded in the debugger or because the assembly is a different version than what's loaded)

Comment: why aren't my solid red dots being hit then? They are located within a controller.

Comment: Have you tried closing your solution and reloading it?  I know sometimes this helps me.

Comment: @MonoDeveloper I'm  not sure. This only happens to me when the assembly isn't loaded or it's out of date.